# TFS 2015 vNext Gated check in reconciliation issues with VS 2013 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I use VS 2013 Updated 3. I am able to check-in and trigger the gated builds but there is no feedback when the action is completed. I've to manually verify the completion from the portal and then do a manual reconciliation. Is this a bug or do i need to install any patch on VS 2013?

Comment: Not sure,you'd need Update 5 for full TFS 2015 compatibility, but the new gated check-in features were introduced after that was released.

Comment: You can install https://catlight.io/ to at least get a pop-up on your system when your builds complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mentioning [Build Notifications application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181725(v=vs.120).aspx). Including upgrade VS 2015 to Update 5 as @jessehouwing mentioned in comment. Also try to open the build notification application, remove the builds from the notification, then close VS, and clear the TFS cache (`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`). After that, re-run VS and Build Notification.